# How to use all the 45 Watt out of the Xiaomi Mi Power Bank Pro 3

Tags: usb, display, power-supply, battery, power

I have been working on this project that consists on making a somewhat portable computer... I intend on using a Raspberry Pi and an old laptop monitor to get the job done. The thing is that I bought a Xiaomi Mi Power Bank Pro 3 to power the computer (due to the pandemic I couldn't get stuff to make my own battery pack) and after some tests to power the monitor via USB-C (up to 45W output) I found out that it doesn't follow USB rules so I got no power whatsoever... The other USB-A ports don't supply enough energy for the backlight to lit up. Is there anyway I can pull the advertised 45 watts out of the USB-C?

[Controller Board](https://www.ebay.com/itm/114210511448?ViewItem=&item=114210511448)

[Power Bank](https://www.ebay.com/itm/Xiaomi-Mi-Power-Bank-3-Pro-20000mAh/264741777969?hash=item3da3d6f231:g:dawAAOSw7pNeyopN)

[Desired Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9mYAz.png)

Please ask me anything that might help you helping me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What's not following the rules? Are you aware that to get 45 watts the charger and device need to negotiate a 45 watt connection?

Comment: @davidgo no, I was not aware of that. I thought it would be as easy as connecting the VCC and the GND. Is there anyway I could deliver the required amount of power to the display controller board using this very powerbank with some sort of power negotiacion circuit in between. Thanks!
Edit: After some web surfing I found this [product](https://www.coolgear.com/product/nano-usb-pd-to-dc-module-pd-negotiation-device) that might solve my problem.

Comment: See https://www.usb.org/usb-charger-pd for an overview ( or Google USB-PD)

Comment: Thanks a lot @davidgo go on and answer the question so I can mark it as solved. c:

Comment: Some googlefoo found this which may be helpful - https://hardforum.com/threads/usb-c-pd-to-12v-dc-barrel-adapter.1976416/

Comment: @davidgo that's exactly what I am looking for, thanks again!